# How to pass the id of one div element to another provided second being executed in loop?

Tags: html, angular

I have two div elements and my requirement is how do I pass the id of  present in second div element and is getting executed in the loop to the first div element button. Here is the sample code :

```
<div style="float: right;">
     <button type="button" (click)="delete(skillGroupAndTypeRow.id);"></button>
</div>
```

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Skill Group Names</th>
      <th>Skill Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr #skillGroupAndTypeRow *ngFor="let group of groups; let i=index;" id="skillRow-{{i}}">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="group-{{i}}"  >
        </td>
        <td>{{group.name}}</td>
        <td>{{group.type}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So how do I pass the Id of  tag into the delete button present in above div.

With this approach there is a error saying cannot read id of undefined.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want to create is a dynamic component, and load/delete said component with the click of a button. Or have all your tables data in an array, and remove chosen object from array with a click event.

Comment: yes exactly , this is what I have been looking for @crooksey

Comment: https://rangle.io/blog/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/ or https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver

Comment: U want to put delete button in action column of table for each row?